# How to return string/int from dbcontext

Tags: c#, linq, dbcontext

I want to get `role_code` from `db.roles` based on `role_id` and then return `role_code` as the result.

I have tried this

```cs
public static string GetRoleCode (int role_id)
{
    string result = "";
    using (var db =new DbContext())
    {
        result = db.roles
            .Where(r => r.Id == role_id)
            .Select(r => new
            {

            }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return result;
}
```

What's missing from my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `result` is a `string`, you can't return with `anonymous` type in `.Select()`.

You should just return the role code as:

```cs
.Select(r => r.Code) // Assume this field you need to return
```

```cs
result = db.roles
    .Where(r => r.Id == role_id)
    .Select(r => r.Code)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or

If you use C# 6 or above, you can use [Null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) as below:

```cs
result = db.roles
    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Role_Id == role_id)?
    .Code;
```

Comment: i have tried your advice, and its work for me, thank you